# Computed Column Case Output from Different Database

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to select a specific field from my database (using SQLserver), using Access.
The Datatype is a date, and what I want to check is if the date difference between the date I selected and the current date is smaller than 4 days
I'm writing this in Access, as that is where my software is located.
I'm receiving an error "Runtime error 13: type mismatch".
The data type is Date in the column I'm trying to get (ReleaseDate).

```
Dim SQLVerDate As Date
SQLVerDate = "SELECT ReleaseDate FROM tblVersionReleasesNew ORDER BY ReleaseDate DESC"
If DateDiff("d", Date, SQLVerDate) < 4 Then
    VerLbl.ForeColor = 0
Else
    VerLbl.ForeColor = 10
End If
```

Comment: This is not how data works in any application. You have a date variable and you are trying to assign it a string value. You have to execute a query and then assign the value of your variable to the result of the query.

Comment: I don't "get" your code.  You define a SQL query which presumably will return many records, then you compare that _string_ using the `DATEDIFF` function.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I attempted to use MAX(ReleaseDate), but that didn't work either..

Comment: @SeanLange, is that not how I execute a query from VBA?

Comment: No. How does VBA know that is a query? It is just a string.

Comment: You never execute any query.  You just assign your intended query to a string called `SQLVerDate`, but you never ran it if I'm not mistaken.  So, you should research how to execute a SQL query from VBA.

Comment: Also, your query indicates it is expected to return more than 1 row. Does that mean you should be using top 1? Or maybe MAX? Or if you need to process all the rows then you need some kind of a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways to accomplish this.

If you just want the latest ReleaseDate in table, use Max() function in query:

```
Dim rs AS DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset "SELECT Max(ReleaseDate) FROM tblVersionReleasesNew"
If Date() - rs!ReleaseDate < 4 Then
    VerLbl.ForeColor = 0
Else
    VerLbl.ForeColor = 10
End If
```

Or use domain aggregate function:

```
If Date() - DMax("ReleaseDate","tblVersionReleasesNew") < 4 Then
    VerLbl.ForeColor = 0
Else
    VerLbl.ForeColor = 10
End If
```

Or instead of VBA and label control, use textbox and Conditional Formatting with domain aggregate expression in textbox.